# how to use Excel in android application

Tags: java, android, excel

So, i building an application that doing that:
when the user write a name in edittext and click a button, i want the application to give the user some information about this name,
I have an Excel with that information, how can i add this Excel into my apk
And how can i read it from there? for each name his specific information..

the Excel look like that:

http://s18.postimg.org/ofcgudlk9/image.jpg

So for example, when the user write "android" in the edittext and click the button, i want a toast that will show "number: 1234 , more: good"

Any Idea?

Comment: Based on your question and the comments you have left below, you need to be aware that you will need to do some work and reading yourself, in addition to any help you receive here.  SO will not spoon-feed you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) library to read or write to an Excel file , you have to put your excel somewhere in Sdcard then with jxl you can read or write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the Excel file in your app.

You can export the excel file as a CSV file.

Then you can use the csv file with your app or you can use it to create a SQLite database and distribute it with your app.

The csv or SQLite file goes into the assets directory.

You can use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to parse the CSV file.
To distribute an SQLite file with your app you can use [SQLiteAssetsHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: OK, so i convert it to CSV file, now what?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer Json instead of using an excel or CSV file as suggested in other answers. With Json you can easily read and search through your data.

So here is the approach,

> 1. Convert your Excel to Json here -> http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/    Note: Just a service
>      that I found in Google. You may search for better services.
> 2. Now place the Json in /res/assets folder. If there is no assets folder then create it.
> 3. Now Load the Json at the start of your application. Google about parsing Json files, If you are not aware of it.
> 4. Whenever user enters something, Please search the Json and show the respective content.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ty for the Comment, how can i work with json? do you have any code that i can use to get my data?

Comment: You can parse your Json file and search it for a specific name with Google's gson library.  Basically what you want to do is a group of tasks as myself and others suggested as steps. You can now Google for each step to finish up your task.

Answer (score 0):

you may try use POI HSSF/XSSF to just read the excel file.